# iOS app runs at iPhone4 resolution on my iPhone5s?

Tags: ios, xcode

Just loaded my app onto my iPhone 5s, and did the same for my colleagues (all on iPhone 5s).

While the app runs at the correct resolution in all of the Xcode simulators, it runs at (what looks like) iPhone4 resolution on our actual devices.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have the 4" launch image?

Comment: Hmm, could be a good lead. One of the things I did before running it this time was I implemented a Launch Image xib. How can I check?

Comment: The "Launch Screen file" is only used with iOS 8. If you support iOS 7 or earlier you also need to standard launch images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you include the LaunchImage for iPhone 5, the app will build at that resolution.

The same goes for the new iPhone 6's - until you include those launch images your app will be scaled.